# How to change the orientation of a html header?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in HTML and web design, and I am making a simple header for my website. I have a logo image aligned to the left using `float left`. I also have a simple navigation bar including all the other web pages that I have on my website in the header, and it is also aligned, this time to the right, with `float right`. However, the webpage displays not in the way I want it. Instead, it displays like this:
[image]

As you can see, the navigation bar and image are all floated to the right and left respectively, but the navigation bar is clearly below the image and the title, instead of being on the same horizontal block. How can I change this? I want the navigation bar to be directed right of the title and image. I tried using `display: inline` but it did not work.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Change the position in HTML. E.g. you now have `<div class="logo"></div> <nav></nav>`, reverse this, so the nav come BEFORE the logo (`<nav></nav> <div class="logo"></div>`) and the spacing will be gone

Comment: @elveti Thanks it works! Why does it work though?

Comment: you should have to use flex properties for that.

Comment: @Paulie_D fine I'll use code snippets next time.

Comment: @AaronyJamesys hard to say why exactly. It happens mostly when the left floated element is too wide (and would overlap the right-floated element). In that case the first element has priority (so the title is placed, then the navigation is placed underneath because it doesn't have space anymore). If you reverse the order, the navigation will come first and thus have priority. The next element (the title) will then come later, fill the remaining space on the left and wrap if needed. BTW as others mentioned: `flex` is almost always better (it's newer), but can be complicated for beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget `float`. Use `flex`

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Read about `CSS flex-box layout`. It will speed up your work and make it more pleasant.

Answer (score -1):

**pls adding header class**

```
.header {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```